# Magento 2: Set default attribute option as None

Tags: magento2, attributes

I want to have default attribute value as `None` but whenever I create an attribute, it's first option value is set as default. Please check attached image. How I can configure it so that it's default value will be `None` instead of first entered option.

[image]

Whereas in Magento 1, I was not forced to have a default option selected as depicted in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can add empty additional option, put that as default. after that you can delete that option.

Answer (score 1):

Use browser console and remove `checked` property and/or as @vijay suggests, add a new, additional empty option and remove it

Comment: This does work, but every time a new attribute is added, the process must be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in base Magento  installation.

Comment: There must be a solution to it otherwise we must assign a value to this attribute for all products if this attribute is assigned to attribute set using which we will create a new product. In this case it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Default value used only when user edit product. If you add attribute or change default value this do not apply to existing products

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something here. It's not an required attribute. It should not force me to have a default selected option. In Magento 1 I was not forced to have a default option selected. Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone - add a new attribute value, select it as default then delete it. None will then be selected and it will function as normal

Answer (score 0):

I tried to unset the option via browser console and save it which did not work.
Adding an empty value as default option is also no solution in my case.
But if you have access to the database you can unset the default value there:

```sql
UPDATE eav_attribute SET default_value = NULL WHERE attribute_code = 'your_attribute_code'
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the first option 'None'. Despite setting 'Required' to 'No', it's still a generated drop-down, and therefore requires it's own value for 'None'.